# Android ExpandableListView get group number when closing group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to handle onclick on groups of a custom ExpandableListView. With this code I am getting the number of group when clicking on it:

```
exList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

        Log.i("group position", groupPosition + "");
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am adding the simplified code. I hope you can figure out what the problem might  be:

```
public class ProductLists extends Activity {
    private static final String G_TEXT = "G_TEXT";
    private static final String C_TITLE = "C_TITLE";
    private static final String C_TEXT = "C_TEXT";
    private static final String C_CB = "C_CB";

    List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();    
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

    List<Map<String, Boolean>> groupCheckBox = new ArrayList<Map<String,Boolean>>();
    List<List<Map<String, Boolean>>> childCheckBox = new ArrayList<List<Map<String,Boolean>>>();
    String loadedexpanded;
    String upperString;
    int number, k_num, k_num2;

    String etext_newitem;
    EditText et_newitem;

    String CheckedItem;
    String CheckedItems;
    ExpandBaseAdapter adapter;
    ExpandableListView exList;

    HotOrNot info;
    ArrayList<String> grpsfav = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> OftenUsedAll = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> OftenUsedID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> OftenUsedName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> OftenUsedNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button sqlExp, sqlAdd;
    ArrayList<String> PRLists = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PRListsR = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PRListsID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PRLists2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> todoItemsID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> todoItemsNAME = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> usable_chars = Arrays.asList(";", "'", "/", "\"", "%", "'\'", "$", "+", "-", "=", ":", "_");
    ArrayList<String> todoItemsTEMP = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> todoItemsIDTEMP = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> todoItemsNAMETEMP = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> inners = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList result2;
    Button sqlView, sqlValami;
    Cursor c, c2;
    String newlistname, modifiedlistname;
    String loadedCapital, loadedshowhints;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    ExpandableListView expandlist;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    int width;

    List<String> selectionList = Arrays.asList("Rename", "Delete");
    List<String> selectionListA = Arrays.asList("Add item", "Rename group", "Delete group");
    CharSequence[] selectionList2, selectionList2A;
    String rowIdtobemodified, rowIDtobedeleted;
    int groupPosition;
    int childPosition;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    Dialog dialog_newitem, dialog_newgroup;

    Dialog dialog_renamelist, dialog_deletelist;
    EditText et_renamelist, et_deletelist;
    //String etext_renamelist, etext_deletelist;
    String renamelist_name, deletelist_name;
    Spinner SPProductLists3, SPProductLists32;
    Button btn_rename_save, btn_rename_cancel, btn_delete_save, btn_delete_cancel;
    String allerrors_newproductlistdialog;
    ArrayList<String> errors_addgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selected_item_from_lists_torename, selected_item_from_lists_torename2;
    List<String> nonusable_chars = Arrays.asList(";", "'", "/", "\"", "%", "'\'", "$", "+", "-", "=", ":", "_");

    int max;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_productlists3);

        exList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.layoutExListView);

        info = new HotOrNot(this);
        info.open();
        //----------------------------query tables--------------------------------
        c = info.showAllTables();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                PRLists.add(c.getString(0));

            }while (c.moveToNext());
         }
         if (PRLists.size() >= 0)
         {
             for (int i=0; i<PRLists.size(); i++)
             {
                Log.d("PRLists(" + i + ")", PRLists.get(i) + "");
             }
         }

        //Declare base adapter
        max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PRLists.size(); i++) 
        {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(G_TEXT, PRLists.get(i).replaceAll("_", " ").substring(2, PRLists.get(i).replaceAll("_", " ").length()));

            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            if (!PRLists.get(i).equals("PR_Often_Used"))
            {
                Log.i("tabla", PRLists.get(i) + "");
                c2 = info.getAllTitlesPRtables(PRLists.get(i));
                if (c2.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        children.add(curChildMap);
                        curChildMap.put(C_TITLE, c2.getString(1).replaceAll("_", " "));
                        curChildMap.put(C_TEXT, "Child ");
                    }while (c2.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("tabla", "PR_OFTEN_USED");
                c2 = info.getAllTitlesOftenUsed("PR_Often_Used");
                if (c2.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        children.add(curChildMap);
                        curChildMap.put(C_TITLE, c2.getString(1).replaceAll("_", " "));
                        curChildMap.put(C_TEXT, "Child ");
                    }while (c2.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            if (children.size() > max)
            {
                max = children.size();
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }
        info.close();

        for ( int i = 0; i < PRLists.size(); i++) {
            List<Map<String, Boolean>> childCB = new ArrayList<Map<String,Boolean>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) { //leghosszabb belso lista merete
                Map<String, Boolean> curCB = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                childCB.add(curCB);
                curCB.put(C_CB, false);
            }
            childCheckBox.add(childCB);
        }

        adapter = new ExpandBaseAdapter(ProductLists.this,
        groupData, childData, groupCheckBox, childCheckBox);
        exList  = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.layoutExListView);
        exList.setAdapter(adapter);
        exList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        exList.setDivider(null);

        int groupCount = adapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
            exList.collapseGroup(i);
        }

        exList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.multiple_checkbox);
                checkBox.toggle();
                if (childCheckBox.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(C_CB)) //ha itt hiba akkor azert van m az adapterben akkor allitok cb statuszt ha van children, es mivel ha nincs akkor ez ertelmezhetetlen
                {
                    childCheckBox.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(C_CB, false);
                }
                else {
                    childCheckBox.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(C_CB, true);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        exList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                //Log.i("group position", groupPosition + "");
                Toast.makeText(ProductLists.this, "group position" + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("PRLists.get(groupPosition)", PRLists.get(groupPosition));
                if (PRLists.get(groupPosition).equals("PR_Often_Used"))
                {

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        exList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                    groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                    childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

                    selectionList2 = selectionList.toArray(new CharSequence[selectionList.size()]);
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProductLists.this);
                    builder.setItems(selectionList2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int item) 
                        {
                            if (selectionList2[item].equals("Rename"))
                            {
                            }
                            if (selectionList2[item].equals("Delete"))
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                    groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                    Log.i("tablagrp", PRLists.get(groupPosition) + "-" + groupPosition);

                    selectionList2A = selectionListA.toArray(new CharSequence[selectionListA.size()]);
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProductLists.this);
                    builder.setItems(selectionList2A, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int item) 
                        {
                            if (selectionList2A[item].equals("Add item"))
                            {
                            }
                            else if (selectionList2A[item].equals("Rename group"))
                            {
                            }
                            else if (selectionList2A[item].equals("Delete group"))
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    public void refreshList() {
        if (PRLists.size() >= 0)  {
            PRLists.clear();
            PRListsID.clear();
        }
        groupData.clear();
        childData.clear();
        groupCheckBox.clear();
        childCheckBox.clear();

        info = new HotOrNot(this);
        info.open();
        //----------------------------query tables--------------------------------
        c = info.showAllTables();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                PRLists.add(c.getString(0));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        if (PRLists.size() >= 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<PRLists.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.d("PRLists(" + i + ")", PRLists.get(i) + "");
            }
        }
        ExpandBaseAdapter adapter = new ExpandBaseAdapter(ProductLists.this, groupData, childData, groupCheckBox, childCheckBox);
        ExpandableListView exList  = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.layoutExListView);
        exList.setAdapter(adapter);
        max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PRLists.size(); i++) 
        {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(G_TEXT, PRLists.get(i).replaceAll("_", " ").substring(2, PRLists.get(i).replaceAll("_", " ").length()));
            ArrayList parent = new ArrayList();
            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            ArrayList child = new ArrayList();
            c2 = info.getAllTitlesPRtables(PRLists.get(i));
            if (c2.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    children.add(curChildMap);
                    curChildMap.put(C_TITLE, c2.getString(1).replaceAll("_", " "));
                    curChildMap.put(C_TEXT, "Child ");
                }while (c2.moveToNext());
            }
            if (children.size() > max) {
                max = children.size();
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }
        info.close();
        for ( int i = 0; i < PRLists.size(); i++) {
            List<Map<String, Boolean>> childCB = new ArrayList<Map<String,Boolean>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
                Map<String, Boolean> curCB = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                childCB.add(curCB);
                curCB.put(C_CB, false);
            }
            childCheckBox.add(childCB);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //expand only those groups that was expanded by the user
        for (int i = 0; i < grpsfav.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("grpsfav items", grpsfav.get(i));
            exList.expandGroup(Integer.valueOf(grpsfav.get(i)));
        }
    }
    //the Holder class-------------------------------------------------------------------

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView cTitle;
        // TextView cText;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    public class ExpandBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        String loadedFontSize, loadedFontType, loadedConfDel, loadedshowhints; 
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

        Context mContext;
        private static final String G_TEXT = "G_TEXT";
        //private static final String G_CB = "G_CB";
        private static final String C_TITLE = "C_TITLE";
        private static final String C_TEXT = "C_TEXT";
        private static final String C_CB = "C_CB";

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

        List<Map<String, Boolean>> groupCheckBox = new ArrayList<Map<String,Boolean>>();
        List<List<Map<String, Boolean>>> childCheckBox = new ArrayList<List<Map<String,Boolean>>>();

        private Context context;

        ViewHolder holder;

        public ExpandBaseAdapter(Context context,
                List<Map<String, String>> groupData, List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData,
                List<Map<String, Boolean>> groupCheckBox, List<List<Map<String, Boolean>>> childCheckBox) {
            this.groupData = groupData;
            this.childData = childData;
            this.groupCheckBox = groupCheckBox;
            this.childCheckBox = childCheckBox;
            this.context = context;
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.groupitem, null);
            }
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupText);
            title.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupBox);
            if (isExpanded) {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized);
            }
            else {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized);
            }
            return view;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupData.get(groupPosition).get(G_TEXT).toString();
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groupData.size();
        }

        // **************************************
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.cTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_title);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_checkbox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.cTitle.setText(childData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(C_TITLE).toString());
            if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) > 0) {
                Log.i("chlrden", getChildrenCount(groupPosition) + "");
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(childCheckBox.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(C_CB));
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(C_TITLE).toString();
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return childData.get(groupPosition).size();
        }

        // **************************************
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public void SaveExpanded(String key, String value){
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
       }
    public void LoadExpanded(){
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        loadedexpanded = sharedPreferences.getString("expand", "false");
    }
}
```

However, when I click it again, the group closes, BUT i don't get the group number. I only get it, when I open a group.

If I use

```
exList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

        if (groupPosition > 0){
            return true;
        }
         return false;
    }

});
```

I get the group number both times, but then the groups are not opening.

Any ideas?

Comment: You missed something in your Log. `onGroupClick` will definitely pass you the group position regardless of wheter the group gets expanded or callapsed. Regarding your second code block: you always return true so the system will not handle the expanding/callpasing

Comment: I did not miss anything. I tested it many times, I cannot see the log line when I am closing the group. I tried it with toast. I get the messages only on opening.

Comment: I suppose your using the default implementation of the framework and not a customized one. You may provide the relevant code so that the problem can be reproduced

Comment: It's definitely a problem with your code. The expanded group gets collapsed so the onClick works well..but your listener is "lost" anyhow

Comment: I have a setOnChildClickListener and a setOnItemLongClickListener as well, both working fine, however their behaviour is different. I cannot see any other listeners that would override the built-in onGroupClickListener. Yes, the onClick works fine, the groupPosition is lost somewhere...

Comment: The onClick of the ExpandableList works fine but the onClick of your listener callback isn't called anymore. There is no problem with the passed groupPosition variable. If your onClick would be called you would see a log message because groupPosition is of type int..so in any case..it would at least print out "0". So your listener isn't set anymore

Comment: Can you think of any reason for that?

Comment: No idea. But you could show your ExpListView Activity and your adapter code

Comment: I have added the simplified code. I hope you can help me with that

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` your setting up your ExpListView (`findViewById`, adapter, group/child listener etc.). But in `refresh()` your setting up your ExpListView without setting the listener...you only call `findViewById` and set the adapter. You have to do the same like youd did in `onCreate()`.

However I don't think it's neccessary that you "reinitialize" your ExpListView in `refresh()` and you should probably review your code. If you want to I would suggest that you define your ExpListView as member variable and in `refresh` you remove the line

```
ExpandableListView exList  = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.layoutExListView);
```

in your `refresh` method

Comment: That doesn't help. I don't know what I should put the groupclicklistener to the refreshlist(), it would be duplication.

Comment: That's why I suggested you to remove the above mentioned line from your `refresh()` method. If this doesn't work I can't help you anymore because your code is very hard to read..don't be mad but it's really a mess

Comment: I know, I know. I have just opened a new topic. If that can be solved, I do not the solution for this problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I found another expand.lv tutorial where I also don't get any toast msg when closing the group. Maybe this is a bug? http://roningamer.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-custom-expandable-list-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

However the onGroupClickListener is not working properly, I have found another solution. I used `setOnGroupExpandListener` and `setOnGroupCollapseListener` and they are working magically!